# Copy colored cells from multiple sheets & paste into one sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I've got multiple sheets with data in them. I've highlighted some rows in each sheet with different colors (mostly green), and I'd like to copy these, into *one* sheet

What I've got so far

```
Sub Copy_If_colored()
   Dim sh As Worksheet, N As Long
   Dim i As Long, M As Long, J As Long
   Dim xCell As Range, xRg As Range


   N = Sheets.Count - 1
   M = 2

   For i = 1 To N
   J = Sheets(i).UsedRange.Rows.Count
   Set xRg = Sheets(i).Range("A1:A" & J)
       For Each xCell In xRg

           If xCell.Interior.Color <> RGB(255, 255, 255) Then
               Sheets(i).Range(xCell).Copy
               Sheets("Recommended").Range("A" & M).PasteSpecial (xlValues)
               Sheets("Recommended").Range("A" & M).PasteSpecial (xlFormats)
               M = M + 1
           End If

       Next
   Next i
End Sub
```

I was hoping the  `..<> RGB(255, 255, 255)` would catch any color since it's the value it returns in the default colorcode, right? Or would `xlNone` be more correct?

Comment: RGB(255,255,255) it is white color. By default, there is no color.

Comment: What is `xRg` ?

Comment: using `<> xlNone` would be more apt

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a few mistakes in your code, here is your fixed code:

```
   Sub Copy_If_colored()
   Dim sh As Worksheet
   Dim i As Long, M As Long
   Dim rngRow As Range

   M = 2 'Start at second row, since first row contains headers

   For i = 1 To Sheets.Count - 1 'Make sure "Recommended" is the last sheet
       For Each rngRow In Sheets(i).UsedRange.Rows 'Going through rows instead of every cell should be considerably faster
           If Sheets(i).Range("A" & rngRow.Row).Interior.ColorIndex <> xlNone Then
               rngRow.Copy Sheets("Recommended").Range("A" & M)
               M = M + 1
           End If
       Next
   Next i
End Sub
```

To only copy the data as values, use this:

```
rngRow.Copy
Sheets("Recommended").Range("A" & M).PasteSpecial xlValues
```

Note that this does not copy formatting, if you need number formats etc. to be copied as well, add this line:

```
Sheets("Recommended").Range("A" & M).PasteSpecial xlFormats
```

Comment: There absolutely was, I noticed as well. Ive tried your code, but with no succes, nothing is copied  nor pasted into the "Recommended" sheet, do you want me to post pictures of how the sheets look like?

Comment: @AndreasRasmussen Yes, please. I tried the code on some sample data and it worked as intended.

Comment: Arrgh, don't mind me, your code is working as it should, i just realised that in my data sheets, there wasnt any data (and therefor no color) in row A, which is why it didn't copy anything... **however**, it does paste it with formulas (I forgot to mention the data in the cells were formulas..) How do i make it paste values only?

Comment: I've added that to my answer

Answer (score 1):

If You want to compare with `RGB` instead of:

```
If CStr(xCell.Value) <> RGB(255, 255, 255) Then
```

try to use:

```
If xCell.Interior.Color <> RGB(255, 255, 255) Then
```

Also You need to set range `xRg`